# Forum Creation or Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, forums

I am planning on creating a forum website for a specific video game. Is there anything out there that generates a forum style site for you to pay for. This is only a small part of the site and I do not want to build this custom if it is easily purchased or better yet, free.

Is this the right StackExchange site to ask this?

EDIT:
I am just asking if anyone has had a good experience with one in asp.net or mvc

Comment: maybe your google is broken but searching 'free forum' yielded plenty of results for me :D

Comment: I know there are lots out there. I am just asking if anyone has had a good experience with one in asp.net or mvc

Comment: put that in your question then because currently your question is 'does this exist?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best fit for this site, if you want CSS styles go to a Graphic Designer or try out http://www.monstertemplate.com/search/page1.html?keyword=games